# Posso utilizar Css dentro de uma aplicação Swing?

Tags: java, swing

É possivel estilizar uma aplicação java feita em Swing, utilizando css ou javascript?

Comment: Não é possivel. Você precisa utilizar os [**Look and Feels**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) para isso. Se quer estilizar usando css, tente [**JavaFx**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784)

Answer (score -2):

Algumas coisas podem ser feitas no componente. Abaixo um exemplo de utilização do CSS e HTML para um JButton:

```
jbBotao = new javax.swing.JButton();
jbBotao.setText("<html>\n<style>\ndiv {\ncolor: white;\nfont-family:arial;\nbackground-color: black\n}\n</style>\n<div>Teste</div>\n</html>");
```

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta é referente ao uso de estilização sobre toda a aplicação, e não apenas a certos componentes. E isso não vai mudar nada da estilização do botão, somente de seu texto.